# How to retrieve the URL to which the request is sent when the form submit button is clicked??

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, python-requests

I am using this web-app - 'http://podaac-uat.jpl.nasa.gov/mcc/' and I want to know the url of the server to which the request is sent to when I am hitting the submit button. I am writing an API that needs to send the request directly to the server with the required parameters set rather than using the web-app.

Thanks for the help in advance. :)

Comment: _"I want to know the url of the server to which the request is sent to"_ ? What ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly what you are trying to do, one way to find out what the Compliance Checker is trying to do is to capture the traffic when submitting. This can be done using various tools such as [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler), but all modern browsers allow this.

As a test, I have used Google Chrome to check the request made by that submit form:

[image]

POST request includes uploaded data in its body. However, **it is very likely that the site will not allow POST calls from another domain** (i.e. your application) - see [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/44394/how-to-stop-other-websites-from-sending-cross-domain-ajax-requests) and [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)) for references.